# How to consume an API endpoint from Java

Tags: java, spring, rest, consumer

I want to consume a `POST` endpoint from a java desktop application that receives a JSON as a body.

I'm new to the topic and I've been following a lot of tutorials but they usually treat simple calls with no body or simple gets to the APIs.
First I tried with:

`ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(new URI("https:..."), new LoLJSON(), String.class);`

But it throws an exception. I tried to fix it with:

```
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
            messageConverters.add(converter);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Which gives me another error

Now I'm trying with

```
WebClient.builder().build()
                    .post()
                    .uri("https://u.gg/api")
                    .body(Mono.just(new LoLJSON()),LoLJSON.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .doOnNext(response -> System.out.println(response))
                    .block();
```

Which uses reactive technologies, but is also throwing this error:

`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type '' not supported for bodyType=org.white_sdev.desktoprestcall.DesktopRestCall$LoLJSON`

This is the information with which I'm calling the endpoint, it is just a sample call to an endpoint on the internet:

`POST` to `https://u.gg/api`

```
{
"operationName": "FetchMatchSummaries",
"query": "query FetchMatchSummaries($championId: [Int], $page: Int, $queueType: [Int], $regionId: String!, $role: [Int], $seasonIds: [Int]!, $summonerName: String!) {\n  fetchPlayerMatchSummaries(\n    championId: $championId\n    page: $page\n    queueType: $queueType\n    regionId: $regionId\n    role: $role\n    seasonIds: $seasonIds\n    summonerName: $summonerName\n  ) {\n    finishedMatchSummaries\n    totalNumMatches\n    matchSummaries {\n      assists\n      championId\n      cs\n      damage\n      deaths\n      gold\n      items\n      jungleCs\n      killParticipation\n      kills\n      level\n      matchCreationTime\n      matchDuration\n      matchId\n      maximumKillStreak\n      primaryStyle\n      queueType\n      regionId\n      role\n      runes\n      subStyle\n      summonerName\n      summonerSpells\n      psHardCarry\n      psTeamPlay\n      lpInfo {\n        lp\n        placement\n        promoProgress\n        promoTarget\n        promotedTo {\n          tier\n          rank\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamA {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamB {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      version\n      visionScore\n      win\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
    "variables": {
        "regionId": "la1", "summonerName": "whiteking21", "queueType": [], "role": [], "seasonIds": [18]
    }
}
```

And the answer is too long to paste here but you can replicate it on POST man.

[image: POSTMAN call]

I'm not sure if this next part is correct but this is how I'm trying to replicate the JSON Structure for the Body:

[image]

I uploaded the sample code to  GitHub if you want to give it a try, [this is the actual class with the implementation](https://github.com/white-sdev/desktop-restcall/blob/main/src/main/java/org/white_sdev/desktoprestcall/DesktopRestCall.java).

I hope you can help me make this call, solve the issue with any of these calls, or maybe point me into a tutorial that has this info :)
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot construct Spring webClient due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default ClientHttpConnector found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933054/cannot-construct-spring-webclient-due-to-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-sui)

Comment: have you used postman tool before?

Comment: @Gurkirat Singh Guliani, yes, I'm adding the Postman info with which I'm calling the endpoint (Although I have no idea why is my experience with postman related).

Comment: @tgdavies I guess it changed the error I had, I made the update.